# using scanner to check repeating patterns when reading file and using hasNext() and hasNextInt()

Tags: integer, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner, token, file-read

I want to check the input of a text file with the following content:

```
task1 2 3 task2 2 3 task3 2 3 task4 4 5 task5 4 5
task6 7 9 task7 7 9 task8 7 9 task9 7 9
task10 7 9 task11 7 9 task12 7 9 task13 7 9
task14 7 9 task15 7 9 task16 10 11 task17 10 11
task18 10 11 task19 10 11  task20 10 12
```

I tried the following code but it is not working, not sure what is wrong and how to continue to use the Scanner's hasNext() and hasNextInt() to check the content such that it starts with a non-integer such as task1 of alphanumeric characters, followed by 2 integers and then repeating this format throughout the whole file as shown above.

```
Scanner s;
try {
    s = new Scanner(readFile); // create new Scanner scanning file and references variable s to it
    while (s.hasNext()) { // when there is the next string separated by default whitespace

        // check whether contents of file follow the right format
        if (!s.hasNextInt()) { // if s.next() is not an integer
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                if (s.hasNextInt()) { // if s.next() that follows is an integer
                    while (s.hasNext()) {
                        if (s.hasNextInt()) { // if s.next() that follows is an integer
                            System.out.println("The content of the file follows the right format.");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } else { // if s.next() does not follow right format
            System.out.println("The content of the file does not follow the right format.");
            break;  
        }   

    }
s.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually move the scanner through the file.
Use `s.next()` to move forward in the file. Since you're looking for "string int int", there's no need to use `while(s.hasNext)` in the code more than once.

I would make it into a function like this:

```
public boolean isCorrectFormat(readFile){
    Scanner s;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(readFile);
        while (s.hasNext()) { 
                if (!s.hasNextInt()) {                  //If next is not an integer
                        s.next();                       //Move forward
                        if (s.hasNextInt()) {           //If next is an integer
                                s.next();               //Move forward
                                if (!s.hasNextInt()) {  //If s.next() is NOT 
                                                        //an integer, then the 
                                                        //pattern is NOT good
                                        s.close();      //Close the scanner 
                                        return false;   //and return false.
                                }                       //Else it will just continue
                        }
                }
        }
        s.close();
        return true;    //If it went through the loop without issues, 
                        //then the pattern is good.
    }catch(Exception e){
          //do stuff
    }final{
          s.close(); //always
    }
}
```